# Segfault using qsort

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

I need to sort an array of characters in order to iterate over it and print out the unique data points and their count.  This array is held inside a linked list node, and I want to use `qsort` to do this.  Unfortunately, I'm getting a segfault right at that particular line.

```
void printArray(Node_ptr node){

    int count=0; //character count

    char *temp= node->attributes; //duplicate attribute array



    char cur; //current char

    char *outputCat= emalloc(150); //concatenate counts to a single string

    outputCat= "Attribute %d counts are: ";



    qsort(&temp, lineCount, sizeof(char), compare); //sort the array

    ... more code
}
```

I cribbed the compare method from the `man qsort` page

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

  return strcmp(*(char * const *) a, *(char * const *) b);

}
```

In DDD, the qsort line is the one that triggers the segfault.  I originally thought it was due to inaccuracies in the parameters, so I put in some debugging printf statements.  `printf("%s", temp)` prints out 1000 characters, which is exactly what linecount should be.  Chars are 1 byte each, so no need for `sizeof(char)` here.

The error report from ddd on that line is

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.    
0xb7f8c498 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Is this qsort's fault, or something else with my code?

Comment: What role does `outputCat` play in that code? You are assigning to a newly allocated buffer, then assigning it to a constant string (which leaks the buffer, btw), and then doing nothing with it.

Comment: Your `compare` function is incorrect, as @wildplasser points out, but the fix requires altogether abandoning `strcmp`, which compares strings, not characters. To implement it correctly, simply `return *(const char *)a - *(const char *)b;`.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, outputCat is used to build the output string from the array data.  This is why `qsort` functionality is so important.  The entire function is not listed here, since all following code is dependent on the results of the sort.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you should `strcpy(outputCat, "Attribute...");`.

Comment: I considered that, but as the number of unique data points to be counted are unknown at the time of function execution, I have a loop iterating through the array counting the number of values per point.  Those values are then added to the `outputCat` string via `strcat` and `sprintf`

Comment: The line `outputCat= "Attribute %d counts are: ";` doesn't do what you think it does. Marcello Cantos is correct.

Comment: I realized that, and switched to strcpy in the function.  It was that heads up that made me look at it in the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
qsort(&temp, lineCount, sizeof(char), compare);
```

Should be:

```
qsort(temp, lineCount, sizeof(char), compare);
```

You do not need to pass the address of a pointer!

`qsort`'s first argument is a pointer, so if you pass it a pointer, you do not need to use the address-of operator, else you're passing a pointer to a pointer, which is not what you want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort characters, the first argument to qsort() should be a character pointer, not a pointer to a character pointer. The same for the strcmp()

Also: please add the definition for struct node.